# jenkins unable to create test-reports folder in workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins

Issue:

When i run the Jenkins job it is unable to create the unit test results.

Steps executed:

I created a job to run unit tests for an iOS app.
when i go the the workspace using the terminal and run the script to execute unit tests , it is creating test-reports folder with reports.

But when i run the same shell script using Jenkins , it is unable to create the test-reports folder and its contents

kindly help me.
Thanks in advance

Regards
SHAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins user might have different rights for creating folders than you have. Fix the permission and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

I use to start Jenkins using Jenkins.app MAC Application,
But this issue got resolved when i start the Jenkins like below

**$ java -jar jenkins.war**

*I really want to know what are the deferences between below deferent types of starting Jenkins*

1. $ java -jar jenkins.war
2. $ sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
3. Launching Jenkins using MAC Jenkins.app application